# How do I improve model accuracy predicting categorical outcome using categorial predictors?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to predict `Para` using `Col`s. My data is in this format:

```
Record ID Para  Col2     Col3
1          A        x      a
1          A        x      b
2          B        y      a
2          B        y      b
1          A        z      c
1          C        x      a
```

So far, I have tried applying One Hot Encoding (OHE) and running algorithms on the following transformed data:

```
Record Para  a     b      c    x   y  z 
1       A    1     1      1    1   0  1
1       C    1     1      1    1   0  1
2       B    1     1      0    0   1  0
```

The accuracy has been shoddy, highest of 27% with Logistic Regression. I tried kNN, Random Forest, Decision Tree.

Next, I tried encoding the `Col`s to ordinal variables and then reran the algorithms (except Logistic Regression). Similarly poor results.

Am I doing something incorrectly? How can I improve the accuracy?

The raw data is `249681 rows × 9 columns`. Both outcome and predictor columns are categorical. When doing OHE, the data is `5534 rows × 865 columns`.

One thing that I'd like to try is Naive Bayes that calculates P(Outcome|Predictor) and then assign the highest probability predictor to the outcome. Is that a reasonable approach to take?

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: As worded, your problem seems to be expressed for the cross-validated group, not Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

If your categories are exclusive you probably should take a look at [Softmax Regression](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/tutorial/supervised/SoftmaxRegression):

> Softmax regression (or multinomial logistic regression) is a generalization of logistic regression to the case where we want to handle multiple classes. In logistic regression we assumed that the labels were binary: y(i)∈{0,1}. We used such a classifier to distinguish between two kinds of hand-written digits. Softmax regression allows us to handle y(i)∈{1,…,K} where K is the number of classes.